# HTML in BallonText is not rendering in AmChart 2.11.3 pieCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using amChart. I have ballonText property of chart with following string:

```
chartDest.balloonText = "[[title]]<span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>";
```

output of above balloonText in chart is below:(When hover to slice of pie chart)

[image]

title,value and percentage field are render properly but HTML not rending.

I am using AmChart 2.11.3 pieChart. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML in balloon is supported since 3.0 version only.

Comment: zeroin@ Thanks I have no idea about this. thanks to update me. I tried 3.0 version and it work.